# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint - Database set-up

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, database-design, foreign-keys

For a while now I have been researching and reading how to solve my problem, and even thought I have found similar questions, there wasnt any clear answers and everything I tried have not seem to work. I'm a bit familiar with ASP.NET MVC4 (my main abilities rely on PHP & MySQL). For learning purposes I have decided to work on a little project to enhance my C# noobie knowledge but I have got stuck on a little problem, I have a feeling its probably something easy and there is something I'm not keeping in mind, but I would greatly appreciate if you provide me with an idea or solution to the following:

I have created the following model:

```
public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int AddId { get; set; }
    public int HouseNo { get; set; }
    public string AddLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    //public ICollection<GpModel> GpList { get; set; }
    //public ICollection<PharmacyModel> PharmacyList { get; set; }
}

public class GpModel
{
    [Key]
    public int GpId { get; set; }
    public int AddId { get; set; }
    public string GpName { get; set; }
    public Int64 GpTelephone { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AddId")]
    public virtual Address GpAddress { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GpnPharmacy> GpnPharmacies { get; set; }
}

public class PharmacyModel
{
    [Key]
    public int PharmacyId { get; set; }
    public int AddId { get; set; }
    public string PharmacyName { get; set; }
    public Int64 PharmacyTelephone { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AddId")]
    public virtual Address PharmacyAddress { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GpnPharmacy> GpnPharmacies { get; set; }
}

public class GpnPharmacy
{
    [Key]
    public int GpnPharId { get; set; }
    public int GpId { get; set; }
    public int PharmacyId { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("GpId")]
    public virtual GpModel Gp { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("PharmacyId")]
    public virtual PharmacyModel Pharmacy { get; set; }
}

public class MyScriptV1Entities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GpModel> Gps { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PharmacyModel> Pharmacies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GpnPharmacy> GpnPharmacies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<GpModel>()
            .HasRequired(s => s.GpAddress)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PharmacyModel>()
            .HasRequired(s => s.PharmacyAddress)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

The relationships are as follows:

- Each GpModel and PharmacyModel will have an address.
- A PharmacyModel will be "Registered" to 0 or more GpModel
- A GpModel will have 0 or more PharmacyModel "Registered" under their names

Basically Im trying to create a many to many relationship between `Pharmacy` and `Gp` and for this I thought it would be idea to create a separate table `GpnPharmacy` that will hold their IDs and basically "relate" them.

However I think my issue relies on my model builder (I may be wrong) but I can't seem to work around it with the stuff I have found online.

When I fire up the following action on my `GpController` (by using `/Gp/Details/1`)

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var GpModel = MySciptV1DB.Gps.Find(id);
        return View(GpModel);

    }
```

Instead of getting the first Gp details from the database, I get the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.PharmacyModel_dbo.Address_AddId' on table 'PharmacyModel' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I should mention that my application starts by populating the database with data from a SampleData.cs file. The tables have not been created yet for some reason.

If you need more info please feel free to ask and I apologize if Im not clear enough but I'm sort of new to SQL on ASP.NET. Thank you very much for your time.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think try changing the below to false wherever it appears.

```
.WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

This is creating multiple delete cascade paths since deleting an address could delete both a GP and a Pharma, which in turn could cause a problem with cascading deletions to GpnPharmacy table.

You should manually handle deletes if they need to cascade (e.g. via stored procs that will check whether it's safe to delete things and then delete from all tables involved).

Comment: Thank you @Kevin, this actually fixed the error I was having, therefore I'll accept it. But unfortunately I now have another issue (lol). I dont know whether to ask another question here or make another post. However I'll give you a brief incase you or someone else may know how to fix it. My sample data sets the `AddID` value on `GpModel` and `PharmacyModel` so it acts as reference to link the right address to each gp and pharmacy, however this doesnt seem to work. I'm wondering if there is another way to set the value for `public virtual Address GpAddress` on my sample data? Thank you :)

Comment: @Scur4, sorry I don't know the answer to that.  You should post another question.  Good luck.